# What is normally not acceptable to budget in a grant

Tags: funding

I seem to have much more freedom in industry sponsored grants, so this is specific to government grants.  I have never been allowed to budget in a 'Computer', but I can budget in 'a CPU'.  I mostly work with computation, but I assume the computer issue effects many fields.  I also cannot budget in tables and chairs, but through overhead from the institute I can buy those.

Are there other issues for budgeting funding for items that are not allowed that may be more specific to fields?

For example, are there usually restrictions on a microscope, for people in that field.

Comment: This is typically clearly defined in the grant's rules and restrictions.

Comment: So you can buy a microprocessor with the grant, but have to buy the rest of the computer with other funding? Or can you buy a complete computer, but you must list it in the budget as a "CPU"? *Either way, that makes no sense*.

Comment: @Moriarty It makes sense in the domain. When user1938107 says (s)he can buy "a CPU", that usually means server hardware specific to the research project and/or time on a shared cluster (e.g., a public cloud). Buying a complete (desktop) computer, which is going to be used for all kinds of things, is usually a no-no for grants, because this is precisely the type of spending that overheads are for.

Comment: @Moriarty, the way its explained to me, is you can not buy anything that is a complete 'computer' kit, such as a laptop.  I can buy components that are needed, such as a CPU, RAM, SSD.  While the rule might not make sense, it just is.

Comment: Are you sure that it wasn't _GPU workstations_ that were allowed?

Comment: @aeismail It is bundled kits.  However, from the comments and answer, I am learning about the different country rules, so it seems it is impossible to make a list as I thought.  Maybe a more appropriate question would be, which funding agencies have restrictions on budgets that seemingly contradict productivity in the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, Marc has it right - these things need to be defined in the grant rules / grant agreement. There is no universal truth in these matters. For instance,  European Union funded projects almost always contain travel budgets, which can be used for project meetings or research-related trips (e.g., conferences). The  Austrian Science Fundation (FWF), on the other hand, explicitly disallow travel budgets for conference trips and claims that these expenses need to be covered by overheads. Contrary, the Swiss National Science Fundation (SNF) works very similar to FWF, but allows for travel budgets.

That being said, typically only costs that are *specific to running a project* and which would not have been accrued without the project are covered. Besides personnell costs, that typically includes buying special hardware that is essential to the project, but which is not usually used in the rest of the PI's research. What is usually not covered are indirect costs that stem from hiring *any* researcher. This includes mundane things, such as the office space for the researcher, desks, telephony costs, coffee (if you work in a place that buys such things for employees), and IT equipment.

As for the "why are CPUs covered, but not entire computers?" case - I presume that your grant does not allow you to buy just *any* CPU from your grant, but it should allow hardware specific to your project (e.g., buying or renting a powerful server or cluster for number crunching in relation to a computationally intense project). It will likely not allow you to buy just a regular desktop CPU, just as it would not allow you to buy the entire desktop computer.